# Wordpress XML-RPC, How can I get user role or know if a user is able to publish posts?

Tags: php, wordpress, permissions, xml-rpc, roles

I need to check user permissions through `XMLRPC` to know if is able to publish posts.

I checked several `XMLRPC` methods without success, the new `getUsers` from WordPress 3.5 seems ideal but I need to support older versions.

How can I validate the user can publish posts?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using 3.5, it looks like it added a function for this: [getUser](https://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API/Users).
You'll want to check in the 'roles' return value.